# MySQLのダンプデータについて

Tags: mysql

MySQLダンプデータの正式名称について調べています。
公式サイトを確認したら、[SQL フォーマットのダンプファイル](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/mysqldump-sql-format.html)と掲載されていますが、

Q1.ダンプデータは俗称ですか？
正確には、dumpコマンドを使用してSQLフォーマットのダンプファイルを取得するですか？

Q2.SQL フォーマットのダンプファイルとはどういう意味ですか？
・単にデータベース以外のダンプファイルと区別する、という意味ですか？
・それとも、どこかの業界標準組織化団体が、SQL ダンプファイル用のフォーマット形式を規定していますか？

Q3.標準SQL用のダンプファイルフォーマットはありますか？

Q4.MySQLのダンプファイルは、異なるバージョンへはインポート不可ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

憶測で質問の項目を増やす前に、まずキーワードで調べてみてください。
「◯◯とは」でGoogle検索するだけでも殆どの場合はそこそこの情報にたどり着けます。

---

一般的な「ダンプ」とは、ある状態のメモリやファイルの中身を丸ごと (ファイルに) 保存したものになります。

`mysqldump` で取得したダンプ = ファイルの中身はテキストで、元のデータベースを同じ状態で作り直すための SQL 文が記録されています。

**参考:**

[ダンプファイルとは│ネットワーク関連用語集](https://heiwa-net.ne.jp/net-work/about_dmpfile/)

> メモリやレジスタ・ファイル・ディスクなどの中身を丸ごと記録したファイルの事を言います。 また、データベースにおいては、データベース情報をファイルに書き出して保存することダンプと呼びます。 こちらはデータベース移行の際に利用されます。

[【MySQL入門】データベースをdumpする！不測の事態に備えよう](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/82770)

> 出力されたdumpファイルの中身は普通のテキストファイルなので、テキストエディタで見ることができます。色々と情報が記入してあり、読み辛いですが、よくよくみると、CREATE TABLEやINSERT INTOといった見慣れたSQL文を見つけることができます。
>
> ここで種明かしをすると、dumpファイルとは元のデータベースにあったテーブルを作り直すためのコマンドが記載してあるファイルのことだったのです。